# Finding parametric, general and vector equations of a plane given $3$ points.

Tags: vector-spaces

Find the vector, parametric and general equations of the plane through the points $(1, 5, 6), (-3, 5, 4)$ and $(2, 1, 3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**:
 let $$A = (1,5,6), \\ B = (-3,5,4), \\ C = (2,1,3), \\ \vec{AB} = (-4,0,-2), \\ \vec{AC} = (1,-4,-3), \\ \vec{N} = \vec{AB}\times \vec{AC} = \text{det}\begin{pmatrix} i & j & k \\ -4 & 0 & -2 \\ 1 & -4 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$$

and the general equation of the plane is then:
$(x-1,y-5,z-6)\cdot \vec{N} = 0$

Comment: It's weird that this is called the *general* equation of a plane since it only works in $\Bbb R^3$ whereas the vector form works in any dimension ($\ge 2$, of course).

Comment: The general equation of a plane is the same as the vector equation?

Comment: Nope.  The general equation is what BRICS-Fan put here -- it has vectors in it, but notice that it is actually a *scalar* equation.

Comment: And from the general equation, What is the formula to convert to Vector and Parametric equations?